# PHP Codeigniter Unexpected Error(Module 'imagick' already loaded)

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using PHP Codeigniter and unexpectedly this error is occur on live server. Can any one help.

Severity: Core Warning

Message: Module 'imagick' already loaded

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is from php loading up. In your university files there are 2 Lines loading the imagick extension

Assuming a Linux server it's likely located `/etc/php/conf.d` or similar.

Ubuntu server uses `/etc/php7/apache/conf.d` for example assuming your using php as an Apache module

Inside there you should be able to grep for the word imagick 
Just remove one of them

Comment: There is no such file or directory found in apache server.

Comment: How is it set up ? Where is your main php.ini located

Comment: Actually this error is on live server not on local server and I searched php.ini on live server but I didn't found.

Answer (score 3):

In `index.php` file change this line

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
```

to

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'production');
```

Answer (score -2):

I have similar issue when using Codeigniter. The error not show when running in local, but show in server.
My solution is add script below at the end of my index.php

```
ini_set('display_errors','off');
```

Now, my error is gone. Hope this can help.