# Message: Module 'imagick' already loaded

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying implement a custom php query in codeigniter. but I'm getting this error "imagick". 
Here is custom php code that is working perfect

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT id , address, name, lat, lng , planted ,
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * 
  cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * 
  sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM plant 
  HAVING distance < '%s' AND planted is %s ORDER BY distance 
  LIMIT 0 , 10", 
  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $center_lat), 
  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $center_lng), 
  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $center_lat), 
  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $radius), 
  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $planted)); 

 $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
```

Here is the codeigniter code that I have written

```
  $query = "SELECT id, name, lat, lon, 
    (3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * 
    cos( radians( lon ) - radians($lon) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * 
    sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS radius FROM users 
    HAVING radius < $radius ORDER BY radius";

    $query = $this->db->query($query);
```

This error is only occurring for this query only. Please help.

Screenshot: [Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWhVy.jpg)

Comment: I doubt that queries have anything to do with imagick errors. Maybe change your `require`s to `require_once`s

Comment: Hi. Thanks. but the error is occurring only for this query. all other queries in this file are working perfect.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the error message?

Comment: @gabe3886 screenshot is added in question now please check

Comment: @MuhammadRashidAbbas the trace on that states the the issue is on file "unknown" at "line 0".  The issue isn't as a direct result of those queries, but only apparent when running them.  Check all of the files included as part of that process to see if there's a place they are coming from.  Is there anywhere in the code where you are dynamically loading imagick?

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44484478/php-codeigniter-unexpected-errormodule-imagick-already-loaded/54159087#54159087

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini file, maybe there are two `extension=imagick.so` lines. If yes then you should comment one of this

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the error is only for this query. All other queries are working perfect

Comment: I think you should check out your codeigniter libraries which loaded over the script execution

Answer (score 0):

`imagick` is an [image processing and creation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) package that is part of PHP.

By default, it is not used by CodeIgniter although it can be used by the [Image Manipulation Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html) if the developer explicitly chooses it.

Imagick is a dynamic extension to PHP. Normally, it would be loaded in `php.ini` but PHP allows modules to be loaded at runtime using the function [`dl()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php). CodeIgniter does not ever use `dl()` to load `imagick`.

I'm not seeing any obvious use of image manipulation in the query.
The error message says nothing about the database.

Based on those facts, code that runs either before or after the query is producing the error.

Comment: If that is php.ini error then it must occur on other queries on the same page. but this is only for this function that I made for this query.

Comment: Yes, you said that before. But there is nothing in the queries dealing with image manipulation so you are wrong. The error is somewhere else probably after the query runs.

Comment: show us the code for the controller and model that use the second query.

Comment: I changed query to this one and it works.
`$query="SELECT id, name, lat, lon, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lon ) - radians($lon) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM users HAVING distance < $radius ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20";`